# Calling a Self-Executing Function from an Event Listener

Tags: javascript, syntax, dom-events, addeventlistener, self-executing-function

Assume this is my only `HTML`

```
<input id="target" type="number">
```

And assume this is my only `JavaScript`

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
```

I want to execute a `function` whenever the input changes, but I also want to execute said `function` once when the page is loaded (`Self-Executing Function` or `IIFE`). Below are 3 examples, 1 of which doesn't work.

---

---

The following works as expected:

```
target.addEventListener('input', myFunction);

function myFunction(){
    console.log('executed!');
}
myFunction();
```

Here the `function` will be executed when the page is loaded. It will not be executed by the `eventListener`, instead it will log `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined` to the console:

```
target.addEventListener('input', function(){
    myFunction();
});

(function myFunction(){
    console.log('executed!');
})();
```

This one will neither execute when the page is loaded, nor by the `eventListener` and will log `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined` to the console:

```
target.addEventListener('input', myFunction);

(function myFunction(){
    console.log('executed!');
})();
```

---

---

**My question**: Why does the 3rd example not work?

Comment: I don't think the second sample code will work unless you've also got `myFunction` declared somewhere else. It will have exactly the same problem that the third attempt has.

Comment: You're right, I changed it

Comment: actually in second case you declared function in global scope, but in third case you just created function on block scope and executed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of an IIFE is to prevent pollution of the Global (or higher) scope. It doesn't work because an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is an anonymous function. So, when you set up your IIFE syntax with a name, the function name is ignored outside of the expression.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)**:

> IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript
>   function that runs as soon as it is defined.
>
> It is a design pattern which is also known as Self-Executing **Anonymous**
>   Function and contains two major parts. **The first is the anonymous
>   function with lexical scope enclosed within the Grouping Operator ().
>   This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as
>   polluting the global scope.**
>
> The second part is creating the immediately executing function
>   expression (), through which the JavaScript engine will directly
>   interpret the function.

Also, your second example actually does not work for the same reason. You do see your `executed!` message, but that is because the IIFE self-executes. If you proceed to change the input's value, you will get the same error as option #3.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');

target.addEventListener('input', function(){
    myFunction();
});

(function myFunction(){
    console.log('executed!');
})();
```

```html
<input id="target" type="number">
```

Comment: Can't imagine why this is down voted. The answer is correct, it has supporting documentation and an running example.

Comment: "It doesn't work because an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is an anonymous function" is wrong. An IIFE is anonymous if you don't name it. But in the OP's example it is named. The problem is around scoping. Delete your answer.

Comment: @marekful No, it's not wrong. Although the OP named the function, that name is ignored because an IIFE is supposed to be an anonymous function. Read my documentation from MDN, which explains that the syntax within the grouping operator is set up so as not to pollute the Global scope. That's the whole point.

Comment: @marekful It's the same idea as `var x = function foo(){...}`. In a function expression the name is ignored. You can't execute `foo()` in this example, only `x()`;

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that naming the IIFE actually had a use.. 

I read an article about this (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) that shows a few examples of a named IIFE, even the author states "an Immediately Invoked Function Expression can be either anonymous or named", but he fails to mention that naming it doesn't actually do anything..

Comment: You could 'export' the reference to an IIFE only if it's named. Consider this `var n;
(function someName() {
  n = someName;
})()`. I still argue that those references are unavailable because the parentheses used to wrap the expression create a scope which is not available to the outer scope.

Comment: @marekful no, the name on a named function *expression* is never exported to the enclosing scope. (And parentheses never affect scope anyway.) The name is only "visible" inside the function.

Comment: @marekful Parentheses have nothing to do with scope, they just enclose an expression, which will turn what would be a function declaration into a function expression. Function expressions are not hoisted no matter how many parentheses you put around them, so even though you can name them, the name will not be visible outside their body. Naming these function expressions has little use, except trivial examples like defining a factorial recursive IIFE, so the MDN guys themselves call them 'anonymous'. Though I find the wording rather poor, it clearly refers to the fact that they are not hoisted.

Comment: @kuroineko While it's true that function expressions aren't hoisted, this is not the reason that the name in a named function expression is not accessible outside of the expression. If it were just about hoisting, then you would be able to access the function name in code that comes *after* the function expression is declared, which we know you can't.

Comment: well ok, their name is not exported into the current scope at all. That's what the "anonymous" term refers to.